# WxPython: 'App' object has no attribute 'Mainloop'

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

So, I was trying to do the RealPython tutorial on making apps with WxPython, and I ran into an error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'App' object has no attribute 'Mainloop'
```

I have tried everything, but it always gives me that error.

How do I fix it?

For reference, here is the code I was trying to run:

```py
import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title="Hello, world!")
frame.Show()
app.Mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`app` has a `MainLoop` attribute, not a `Mainloop` note the Capital "L"

For future reference you can use the `dir` function i.e.

```
print (dir(app))
```

that will show you what is available.

```
import wx
app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(parent=None, title="Hello, world!")
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really helps.